# What defines whether a CPU should be in LGA of PGA package?

Tags: cpu, packages

All modern Intel CPUs I know are in LGA package. At the same time, AMD CPUs mostly are in PGA packages, with only server ones packaged in LGA.

What are the reasons for Intel to use and AMD to not use LGA for majority of their CPUs?

Comment: My guess would be that it's mostly marketing stuff.

Comment: My guess would be that the reasons are purely business-related and have no technical basis at all.

Answer (score 1):

LGA devices can be soldered down with low cost SMD soldering techniques, as well as being socketed. Intel do solder them down on quite a few of their motherboards.

Having the relatively weak and vulnerable pins on the motherboard also means that if one breaks you only need to replace a £100 motherboard, instead of a £300 CPU.